# MYSQL Выборка с указанием даты

Tags: php, mysql

Подскажите пожалуйста как сделать выборку из базы по дате, есть столбец `created` в котором дата записи, как например вывести записи с 10.10.2010 по 11.11.2011 ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`SELECT * FROM table_name WHERE created BETWEEN '2010-10-10' AND '2018-11-11'`

https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_between.asp документация по оператору `BETWEEN`

Я удивлен что в гугле вы не нашли ответ на данный вопрос т.к его решений море.

Дополнение

1) Для того чтобы все корректно работало надо дату привести к формату `Y-m-d` например `2011-12-23`

2) `SELECT * FROM table_name WHERE created >= '2010-10-10' AND created <= '2011-11-11'` - то же самое но с возможностью исключить границы диапазона из условия отбора. для этого заменяем `'>=', '<='` на `'>', '<'`

Comment: `SELECT * FROM table_name WHERE created >= '10.10.2010' AND created <= '11.11.2011'` - тот же самый запрос но с другим синтаксисом, который, на мой взгляд, легче запомнить.

Comment: Не просто легче, а ещё и более управляемо. Не надо знать, включаются или нет границы в выборку, - сразу видно.

Comment: И разумеется, никто не учел, что BETWEEN '11.01.2010' AND '10.11.2011' не вернет ни одной строки.

Comment: Выглядит нормально, но Ипатьев прав: обратите внимание на формат даты, должно быть '2010-10-11', '2011-11-13' и т.п. -- из очереди проверок.

Comment: Спасибо всем, я дополнил ответ!

Comment: Благадос.Благадос.